# Find value in an object and set the value in another object | javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, foreach

I have two objects with a structure like below:

```
const pageContent = 
[
    {
        header: 'title 1',
        subHeader: [ 'subtitle 1']
    },
    {
        header: 'title 2',
        subHeader: [  ]
    },
    {
        header: 'title 3',
        subHeader: [ 'subtitle 2', 'subtitle 3', 'subtitle 4' ]
    }
]

const subPageContent = 
[
    {
        masterHeader: ' ', // === header: 'title 1'
        header: [ 'subtitle 1' ]
    },
    {
        masterHeader: ' ', // === header: 'title 3'
        header: [ 'subtitle 2' ]
    },
    {
        masterHeader: ' ', // === header: 'title 3'
        header: [ 'subtitle 3' ]
    },
    {
        masterHeader: ' ', // === header: 'title 3'
        header: [ 'subtitle 4' ]
    }
]
```

**EDIT-NOTE:** subPageContent-Object was wrong defined.

At the moment, both objects are separated, but will be concatenated in a further step. However, I need for each 'header' of subPageContent the corresponding 'masterHeader', which can be found within the pageContent as 'header'

So what I have is:

```
function search(searchTerm, array){
    for ( let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if ( array[i].subHeader[i] === searchTerm ) {
            return array[i].header
        }
    }
}

let searchTerm = 'subtitle 1'
let resultObject = search(searchTerm, pageContent)
```

This works fine, in case I have only one value within my subHeader-Array of pageContent.

I struggle with the iteration over an array with more than one value. I thought I would do a second for loop and then return the corresponding header:

```
function searchTwo(searchTerm, array) {
    for ( let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for ( let j = 0; j < array[j].length; j++) {
            if ( array[j].subHeader[j] === searchTerm ) {
                return array[j].header
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know, how i can loop over an array within an object? And once I found that object set the header as masterHeader value within the subPageContent?

The next step, would be, to build a forEach-Loop, so it will search the missing masterHeader for each element within the subPageContent-Object.

Comment: Are there any chance of the `header` array being only a partial match? E.g. will this occur: `header: [ 'subtitle 2', 'subtitle 3']`?

Comment: Well actually not. I had an error in the subPageContent Object, please see the edit. Each header will have only one subtitle.

Comment: see: [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) paired with [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). `return array.find(o => o.subHeader.includes(searchTerm))?.header`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @pilchard mentioned in the comments, you can use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) in conjunction with [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to implement your `search` function where the `subHeader` property is an array. You can then use this function in combination with a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to update the `subPageContent` array with the `masterHeader` values:

```js
const pageContent = 
[
    {   header: 'title 1',  subHeader: [ 'subtitle 1']  },
    {   header: 'title 2',  subHeader: [  ]  },
    {   header: 'title 3',  subHeader: [ 'subtitle 2', 'subtitle 3', 'subtitle 4' ]  }
]

const subPageContent = 
[
    {   masterHeader: ' ',  header: [ 'subtitle 1' ]  },
    {   masterHeader: ' ',  header: [ 'subtitle 2' ]  },
    {   masterHeader: ' ',  header: [ 'subtitle 3' ]  },
    {   masterHeader: ' ',  header: [ 'subtitle 4' ]  }
]

function search(searchTerm, array) {
    return array.find(({ subHeader }) => subHeader.includes(searchTerm))?.header
}

subPageContent.forEach(o => o.masterHeader = search(o.header[0], pageContent) || o.masterHeader)

console.log(subPageContent)
```

Note we use `|| o.masterHeader` in the updater so that if the `header` value is not found in any `subHeader` array (in which case `search` will return `undefined`), the value of `masterHeader` remains what it was.

Comment: Thanks @Nick that works perfect. The funny point is, I ve had a similar idea to solve that problem, but I restructured an Array and not the object, itself. Nevertheless, I wouldn't found the solution anyway, because I don't understand the '?' behind includes: `return array.find(({ subHeader }) => subHeader.includes(searchTerm))?.header` can you please explain me this line of code or send me a link where I can read more about this. **Thanks a lot**

Comment: @VebDav The `?.` is [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), basically it means that if an object is `null` or `undefined`, (for example, if `find` didn't find a match) then attempting to access a property of that object just returns `undefined` instead of throwing an error. Note in your case if the `subHeader` arrays are guaranteed to contain all the `subPageContent`  `header` values, you could just use `.` instead.